# No boot option. Enter BIOS directly

Tags: boot, system-installation, hardware

I made an image of my Ubuntu, then I tried to install again in my Laptop. But, there wasn't booting from USB, then I disabled all boot options, except USB. But it did not work.

When I went to enable all boot options again, they are all "gone". In BIOS, boot options Tab, there is nothing (no CD, no HD...). And when I turn on the computer, it enters directly in BIOS (without pressing any button).

I already tried to restore the default BIOS options and remove CMOS battery, but the problem persist.

Anyone have seen such problem?

Comment: You have tried to restore default BIOS... have you tried Hard Reset? Remove CMOS battery... sorry I think if you do it you won't be able to use your motherboard anymore. Now, before trying to do a Hard Reset, have you tried to enable/disable Legacy USB support, or tried to enable Legacy/CSM/Non-UEFI boot? And just one more thing... are you sure you have the two power cable supplies connected to the motherboard?

Comment: What brand and model is your laptop?

Comment: I already tried enable/disable this and others options...nothing. When I turn on with the USB stick plugged, appear only one boot option, from USB. When I try to load from USB stick, the screen just blinks. About the cables, I don't completely disassembled the notebook. I just opened a little to reach the CMOS battery. I didn't touch any MB cable.

Comment: It's a G55VM ASUS.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CMOS battery if you removed it. If you replaced your CMOS battery after removing it, you may have a problem with a usb port or controller. You can contact Asus support at http://support.asus.com/ServiceHome.aspx?SLanguage=en